# Operator '+' cannot be applied to 'int', 'java.lang.Object'

Tags: java, arraylist

I've just start learning how to manipulate array list.

I have a little probleme while counting the sum of ***myArray*** 
------> the error is ***Operator '+' cannot be applied to 'int', 'java.lang.Object'***

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    ArrayList<Integer> myArray  = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    myArray.add(6);
    myArray.add(2);
    myArray.add(1);
    int x = 0;
    Iterator myIterator = myArray.iterator();
    while (myIterator.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(myIterator.next());
        x = x + myIterator.next();
    }
}
```

Comment: Iterator should be parameterized. Iterator<Integer> myIterator = myArray.iterator();

Comment: @vitalh that's the answer - why not post it as an answer?

Comment: Try extracting  the `next()` value to a variable. That will make it clearer what is happening (hint: you cannot add an Object to an int)

Comment: Did you really mean to call `next()` twice in the loop? With an odd number of entries (like in this example), it will crash. For most cases, it is best to just use a for loop: `for(Integer i: myArray){`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterator should be parameterized. Without specifying the `Integer` type, the compiler assumes `java.lang.Object` type to which the operator `+` is not applied.

```
Iterator<Integer> myIterator = myArray.iterator();
```

Technically, the `+` operator does not apply to objects other than `String`, but `Integer` is a wrapper class for primitive type `int`.
So, in this case, the compiler applies [unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) to get `int`, in which the `+` operator is defined.

Comment: And you rarely need to use the `Iterator` directly. Often a `for(Integer i: myArray)` will do.